# Retrieve parent folder size for each IIS site

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, iis-8.5

Im trying to get a list of sites from IIS (8.5) to include the folder size but cant get this to work.

Below is the current code i have that is working without the size

```
Import-Module webAdministration # Required for Powershell v2 or lower  

$filepath = C:\sites.csv
$sites = get-website

foreach($site in $sites) {
    $name = $site.name
    $bindings = $site.bindings.collection.bindinginformation.split(":")
    $ip = $bindings[0]
    $port = $bindings[1]
    $hostHeader = $bindings[2]
    "$name,$hostHeader,$ip,$port" | out-host
    "$name,$hostHeader,$ip,$port" | out-file $filePath -Append
}
```

I then attempted to add in this line

```
$size = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Force|ForEach {"{0,-30} {1,-30} {2:N2}MB" -f $_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime, ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse|Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum/1MB)}
```

but that didnt work either.

I then attempted with

```
$size = Get-ChildItem $name + "\folderName\" | Measure-Object -Property Length -sum
```

which was getting closer but i think my syntax is wrong with `$name + "\folderName\"` as im getting a series of errors. I say this is close as it has the path to the directory but it doesnt exist. The directory would exist if i can add the foldername to the `$name` variable?

Where am i going wrong? Or how could i retrieve the parent of each website folder size?

Comment: Maybe `Get-ChildItem $site.physicalPath`?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, the `PhysicalPath` property can contain cmd.exe formatted variable `%SystemDrive%`.

When this occurs, you can take the physical path and extract the environment variable name and the remaining path using regex. Pull out the value of the variable and build the path.

```
$filepath = 'C:\sites.csv'
$sites = get-website

foreach($site in $sites) {
    if($site.physicalPath -match '^%(.+)%(.+)$'){
        $sitedir = Join-Path (Get-Content "env:$($matches.1)") $matches.2
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sitedir
    }
}
```

If you confirm this does accurately list the files for each site, it seems you've figured out the measurement portion.

A couple of other suggestions. First, I recommend `Export-Csv` instead of `Out-File`.

Next, instead of opening the file and appending over and over (slow) you can collect all the results and then write them.

```
$results = foreach($site in $sitelist){
    ... code ...
}

$results | Out-File $filepath
```

Or you can use `ForEach-Object` and take advantage of the pipeline.

```
$sitelist | ForEach-Object {
    ... code ...
} | Out-File $filepath
```

A side benefit of `ForEach-Object` is the `-OutVariable` parameter which lets you capture the output in a variable (that is of type `ArrayList`) and see the output (or pipe it on to more commands.)

Considering my recommendations, I'd give this a shot.

```
$filepath = 'C:\sites.csv'
$sites = get-website

$sites | ForEach-Object {

    $ip, $port, $hostHeader = $_.bindings.collection.bindinginformation.split(":")

    $path = if($_.physicalPath -match '^%(.+)%(.+)$'){
        Join-Path (Get-Content "env:$($matches.1)") $matches.2
    }
    else{
        $_.physicalpath
    }

    $size = (Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name       = $_.name
        FullPath   = $path
        IP         = $ip
        Port       = $port
        HostHeader = $hostHeader
        SizeMB     = $size
   }
} -OutVariable results

$results | Export-Csv $filepath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks but the file size using the above was not coming through. It retrieved no value?

Comment: I updated my post